# Ideas for a project in astronomy and deep learning

Tags: astrophysics

I am currently pursuing computer engineering and am in my senior year. I'm looking for a long term project (ideally 2-4 months) in astronomy and deep learning. I have extensively worked on the Galaxy Zoo project and am pretty content with the results. I'm looking for similar projects with easily available datasets. Can someone suggest me some ideas?

Comment: answers and comments on these might be helpful: [How actively is Deep Learning being used in exoplanet identification?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32102) and [Any ideas for an astronomy + ML project?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/28907) and possibly [Open problems in astronomy that an amateur (with a PhD in some other field) would have a chance of solving?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/10387)

Comment: The similar questions are a little old, so I'll throw my 2 cents in and suggest looking at the details of how the SPOC pipeline works for analyzing the enormous amounts of data coming from the TESS space telescope searching for exoplanets.  If you google "TESS SPOC pipline deep learning", you'll find links to papers with more specific details.  I don't know if working with the TESS data would make a good project or not but it's an idea.  Some of the AI was developed for the Kepler mission but there have been new developments since then.  Good luck!